# クロージャでuse演算子を使用すると、どのような仕組みで「変数を親のスコープから引き継ぐ」のでしょうか？

Tags: php

[クロージャは、変数を親のスコープから引き継ぐことができます。 引き継ぐ変数は、use で渡さなければなりません。](http://php.net/manual/ja/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$message = 'hello';

// $message を引き継ぎます
$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
$example();
```

---

**どのような仕組み？**
・引数として渡すわけではない？
・引数とは何が違うのでしょうか？

**「use ($message)」と書いた時点で「親スコープから変数を引き継ぐ」？**
・引数として渡さずとも、スコープ間で値渡しや、参照渡しが出来るということでしょうか？
・意味合い的には引数と同じ？

**エイリアスを作成する [use 演算子](http://php.net/manual/ja/language.namespaces.importing.php)との違い**
・同じ意味？
・エイリアスを作成するから、結果的に「親スコープから変数を引き継ぐ」ということ？？？？

---

Comment: クロージャという仕組みで引き継ぐので、クロージャ自体についてお調べすることをオススメします。

Comment: php公式サイトの表記では「クロージャー」ではなく[無名関数](http://php.net/manual/ja/functions.anonymous.php)が見出しになっていますね。「値渡しによる引き継ぎ」と「参照渡しによる引き継ぎ」は分けて考えた方がわかりやすいのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

個人的にはPHPの挙動だと「親スコープから引き継ぐ」というより「その時点の変数をキャプチャする」と考えたほうがわかりやすいように思いますが・・・。

具体的には、useに指定した変数をフィールドに含んだ [`Closure`](http://php.net/manual/ja/class.closure.php) オブジェクトが作成されます。

```
function getGreeter($msg) {
    return function() use($msg) {
        echo $msg;
    };
}

$hello = getGreeter('hello');

var_dump($hello);
$hello();

/* 出力：
  class Closure#1 (1) {
    public $static =>
    array(1) {
      'msg' =>
      string(5) "hello"
    }
  }
  hello
*/
```

この場合 `$msg` はクロージャにキャプチャされているので、`$hello` を呼び出す際に引数として渡す必要はありませんし、キャプチャ元である `getGreeter()` のスコープにアクセスできなくても動作します。

`use($msg)` を `use(&$msg)` とすると参照でキャプチャすることができますが、これも 
`$closure->static['msg'] = $msg` と、
`$closure->static['msg'] = &$msg` の違いのようなものです。

「エイリアスを作成する use 演算子」は同じuseという英単語が使われたというだけで、機能としては全く別のものです。

- `use Foo\Bar as Bar`
  `Foo\Bar` を `BarAlias` としてuseする＝エイリアスの作成
- `function() use($msg)`
  関数内で `$msg` をuseする＝変数のキャプチャ

Comment: なるほど、挙動としては、Closure オブジェクトのメンバになるわけですね。確かに「親スコープから引き継ぐ」より「クロージャにキャプチャ」の方が分かりやすいと感じました。エイリアスの件ですが、「同じ名称の 演算子なのに機能として全く別のものがある」とは思いもしませんでした